# How to hide buttons on the top toolbar after clicking login using Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8, data-sharing

I am novice to Angular and trying to create an application. I have a home page where I have a toolbar at the top with two buttons namely, 'Admin' and 'Student'. If a person selects admin he would be directed to admin's login screen and if a person selects student he would be directed to student login. After successfully logging in I wanted those two buttons from the toolbar to disappear. I tried reading through data sharing between components but not sure on how to implement it. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

home.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span class="align-content">Online Library Portal</span>
    <button mat-button routerLink="/adminLogin" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="showPage()">Admin</button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="/studentLogin" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="showPage()">Student</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-card-content *ngIf="show">
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Welcome to My Library</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">
        <li>
            If you are an <strong>Admin</strong>, please choose admin option to Login or Register.
        </li>
        <li>
            If you are a <strong>Student</strong>, please choose student option to Login or Register.
        </li>
    </div>

</mat-card-content>
```

home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  show: boolean = true;
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate([''])
  }

  showPage() {
    this.show = false;
  }

}
```

admin-login.component.html:

```
<mat-card class="admin-login">
    <mat-card-header class="login-header">
        <mat-card-title>Admin Login</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content class="content"> 
        <form class="admin-login-form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="admin-user-name">
                            <input matInput placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="admin-password">
                            <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password"
                                name="password" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </mat-card-content> 
    <mat-card-actions class="action">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
    <a class="register" mat-menu-item routerLink="/adminRegistration">Register</a>
</mat-card>
```

After clicking this login button the buttons admin and student from home.component.html must disappear.

admin-login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-login',
  templateUrl: './admin-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-login.component.css']
})
export class AdminLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  username!: string;
  password!: string;
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login() : void {
    if(this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
     this.router.navigate(["admin"]);
    }else {
      alert("Invalid credentials");
    }
  }
  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably worth thinking about what you want to end up with for the actual login auth first before doing this as it will be easier to structure once you have done this. For example you don't want to end up with your admin-login component handling your auth, that would be much better suited to be in a service, as you will presumably want to connect to a login server to do your authentication eventually anyway.

Either way the general idea would be to give your buttons an *ngIf with a condition that you can update when your authorisation changes, which you can keep track of using a service to allow your components to talk to each other. For instance you might have something like:

```
<button
  mat-button
  *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async"
  routerLink="/adminLogin"
  routerLinkActive="active"
  (click)="showPage()"
>
  Admin
</button>
```

And in yout typescript:

```
isLoggedIn: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loginService.userState().subscribe( state => {
    this.isLoggedIn = state;
  }
}
```

There are simpler ways to do this, but because you will inevitably want to move away from handling your authentication on the client side, I think looking in to using services is robably a good start.

Comment: if you use a variable **not** use `|async` |async is for observables, so you can use `*ngIf="loginService.userState() |async` -remember in this case declare as public the service in constructor: `constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}`

Comment: In which typescript file should I add that piece of code? I'm new, please help.